# How do I generate a multipart/mime message with correct CRLF in Python?

Tags: python, mime

I need to generate a multipart/mime message to send as a response to a HTTP request but am hitting either a bug or limitation in the Python email.* package.

The problem is that using Python 2.6, the `message.as_string()` call below generates a string with \n rather that CRLF as the line endings:

```
message = MIMEMultipart()
for image in images:
    f = image.open('rb')
    img = MIMEImage(f.read(), _encoder=encode_7or8bit)
    message.attach(img)


message.as_string()
```

There doesn't seem to be any way to persuade it to use the (MIME standard) CRLF. The Generator class that seems it should be able to do this, doesn't.

What have other people done to get round this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a bug in Python that has now been fixed: http://hg.python.org/lookup/r85811

It should now be possible to use the MIME libraries over non-email transports and have sensible things happen.

Comment: Sadly, this isn't present in python 2.7. I'm still trying to figure out a workaround -- I have a multipart message with a binary part, am sending it as a web request.

Comment: @CantucciHQ looks like it went into Python 3.2. AIUI, library fixes back from 3.2 to 2.7 are accepted, so worth filing a bug asking for compatibility to be maintained?

Comment: thanks for that. It's a small script, so I converted it to Python 3 instead. But I'm still having trouble with it. Here's my question -- any thoughts? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19010306/newline-characters-being-interpreted-when-encoding-binary-mimeapplication-in-pyt

Answer (score 2):

What about a simple hack

```
message.as_string().replace('\n', '\r\n')
```

?  Inelegant, but should work (and a bug report should be entered at the Python tracker).

Comment: Thought of that, but if there's \n characters in the body (which is a PNG file, so straight binary) then this will screw it up.
AFAICT, the encode_7_or_8bit doesn't do anything clever to byte-stuff \n characters.

Comment: Oh there's already a bug here: http://bugs.python.org/issue1349106  It's been open since 2005 and for reasons I don't understand seems to be being resisted.

Comment: @Malcolm, by the time you replace newlines, the body's already been coded in some mail-acceptable way, which "straight binary" is most definitely **not** -- it would violate many RFCs.  An encoding that doesn't actually and carefully "modify the payload" to make it RFC-compliant is unacceptable, and using it is _your_ bug, not Python's -- use `encode_base64` for binary payloads!

Comment: Actually, binary is entirely MIME compliant as a transfer encoding - see e.g. http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2045#section-5.2 - but not for transmission over SMTP.  But I'm not sending this over SMTP but over HTTP, which is perfectly happy to ship binary data.
The bug is definitely Python's - it is assuming that all MIME will be transport encoded e.g. by the SMTP layer, but that isn't the case.

Comment: @Malcolm, you're right, by the letter of the RFCs.  However, you did ask "what have other people done", and base64 encoding + the hack I mentioned is no doubt the popular workaround.